# Notations of a indexed famliy and a set of mappings

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two sets.

A mapping $f: X\to Y$ can be seen as a family of elements of $Y$ indexed by $X$, so I see $f$ is also usually written as $(Y_x)_{x \in X}$. Isn't it?

The set of all possible mappings from $X$ to $Y$, I see, has the notation $Y^X$. 
I wonder why it is like the power of some number to another?

How about the power set of $X$ written as $2^X$? I seem to have seen some explanation somewhere, but forget what it says.

Thanks and regards!

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/89428/622) might be helpful, [so would this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75318/correspondences-f-x-to-2y/75320#75320).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation $Y^X$, I think, is motivated by the fact that if $X$ has $n$ elements and $Y$ has $m$ elements, then the set of functions from $X$ to $Y$ will have $m^n$ elements.

The notation $2^X$ for the powerset of $X$ comes from the one to one correspondence between the powerset of $X$ and the set of functions from $X$ to $2 = \{0, 1\}$.